# Como verificar se uma imagem existe num URL remoto?

Tags: php, url, arquivo

De forma a podermos ter a administração de um website a ser realizada a partir de um servidor diferente daquele onde o website está alojado, surgiu o problema de lidar com imagens remotas.

#### Problemas comuns:

- Verificar se a imagem efectivamente existe antes de criar links para a mesma;
- Ao substituir determinada imagem, verificar se a anterior existe para que seja eliminada;
- Verificar se a imagem carregada para o servidor não está com o mesmo nome de uma imagem já existente.

Normalmente, este tipo de operações é realizado com o `is_file()`, mas como o mesmo não suporta URL, apenas caminhos absolutos ou relativos do próprio servidor, fica assim inviabilizado para este cenário.

## Pergunta

Utilizando PHP, como posso verificar se uma imagem remota existe?

Comment: Verificar se existe imagem, ou se existe arquivo? Isso muda bastante a resposta. No quesito arquivo, foi respondido, no quesito imagem mesmo, "chegaram perto". (pode haver um arquivo no local que não seja imagem)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A minha abordagem para lidar com esta questão passa por recorrer à [Biblioteca Client URL (cURL)](https://php.net/curl) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> para recolher o [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Response_codes) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> e com o mesmo saber se existe ou não a imagem no URL indicado:

```
/**
 * URL Exists
 *
 * Verifica se o caminho URL existe.
 * Isso é útil para verificar se um arquivo de imagem num 
 * servidor remoto antes de definir um link para o mesmo.
 *
 * @param string $url           O URL a verificar.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
function url_exists($url) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return ($code == 200); // verifica se recebe "status OK"
}
```

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/minha_imagem.jpg';
if (url_exists($url))
    // encontrei :)
else
    // não encontrei :(
```

---

<sup>**Nota:** Esta solução depende de funções adicionadas a partir do PHP 4.0.2.</sup>

Answer (score 18):

Para isso você utiliza o `file_exists`, além de URL remoto ele funciona com caminhos absolutos ou relativos do próprio servidor, desta forma:

```php
    if(file_exists('http://www.dominio.com/imagens/minha-imagem.jpg')){
       //seu código...
    }
```

outras funções úteis são:

- [is_readable](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-readable.php) - Diz se o arquivo pode ser lido.
- [file](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file.php) - Lê todo o arquivo para um array
- [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) - Lê todo o arquivo para uma string (extremamente útil)
- [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fread.php) - Leitura binary-safe de arquivo
- [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fread.php) - Lê e exibe o conteúdo de um arquivo

Comment: Só lembrando que os resultados da função `file_exists()` são cacheados. Não esqueça de dar uma verificada na documentação no [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: Uma solução para caching de URL: 'http://www.dominio.com/imagens/minha-imagem.jpg?'.(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10)

Comment: Já tive oportunidade de voltar a este assunto, efectivamente pelos testes realizados em PHP 5.3.22, o `file_exists` devolve sempre `FALSE` mesmo tendo a certeza absoluta que a imagem existe e está acessível via URL.

Comment: O problema é que dependendo do tamanho da imagem, vai ser lindo usar `file_get_contents` que retorna todo o conteúdo para uma string :p

Answer (score 7):

Montei a função abaixo que pode verificar tanto imagens quanto páginas web, ou qualquer outro conteúdo que venha da web. Eu obtenho a resposta do `header` da requisição e comparo os códigos. Caso seja `200` ou `302` existe; caso seja `500` tem erro interno no servidor; caso seja `404` não existe.

Vale a pena lembrar que quem irá fazer a requisição é o seu servidor web, e o mesmo deve ter acesso a internet.

```
<?php
function validarext($url)
{
    $validar = get_headers($url);
    $validar = explode(" ",$validar[0]);
    $validar = $validar[1];
    if($validar == "302" || $validar == "200")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

if(validarext("http://www.urldaimagem.com.br/imagem.jpg")){
    //Imagem existe
    echo "Sim";
}
else
{
    //Imagem não existe...
    echo "Não";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No sistema que implementa o fileUpload você faz uma rotina que irá buscar se determinada foto já existe.
Essa função irá ter utilidade pra todos os processos:

1º: Como dito, verificar se a foto existe antes de criar os links para a mesma, como fazer é usando a implementação do file_exists();.
Recomenda-se que utilize um banco de dados pra armazenar o nome do seu arquivo assim podendo requisita-lo e fazer a verificação com o caminho absoluto do seu servidor.

2º: Quando verificado que a imagem existe, e logo foi informado a execução do processo de substituição, você irá deletar a imagem existente usando a função unlink(); e logo depois recuperar a nova imagem do ~temp e renome-a-la para o nome que está no banco de dados.

3º: Faça uma implementação de um padrão de hash para acrescentar ao seus arquivos, toda vez que alguém subir um arquivo, pegue o name do arquivo e concatene com a seguinte instrução
uniquid( rand(6, 8) );

```
<?php

$nome = $_FILE['image']['name'];
$novoNome = $nome . uniquid( rand(6, 8) );
```