# Como inserir uma imagem por parâmetro na url e exibi-lá na tela

Tags: php, get

Preciso que o código faça a verificação se esse parâmetro com a imagem existe, se ele existir, tenho que exibi-lá na tela. Como posso fazer?

Obs: O parâmetro com a imagem deverá ser passado pelo usuário na url. Ou seja, com GET.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como verificar se uma imagem existe num URL remoto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1819/como-verificar-se-uma-imagem-existe-num-url-remoto)

Comment: @JorgeB.na verdade isso não responde minha pergunta, minha dúvida é diferente.

Comment: Ah entendi mal a pergunta. Quando falas em passar esse parâmetro com a imagem queres dizer com o link da imagem certo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['url_da_imagem']))
{
    echo '<img src="'.$_REQUEST['url_da_imagem'].'">';
}
```

No lugar de `$_REQUEST`você pode usar `$_GET`, é que `$_REQUEST` funciona tanto para GET quanto para POST, assim caso necessite pode receber a URL por POST também, sem ter que mudar seu código.

Edit:

Ah, a URL ficaria assim: http://seudominio.com?url_da_imagem=http://dominiodaimagem.com/imagem.jpg

Comment: E para verificar se esse $_GET existe? Estou tentando usar  : <?php if(isset($_GET['image'])) {
 echo 'existe';

}else {  
 echo 'não existe';
}
?> Mas o site quebra...

Comment: Me defina melhor "quebra". E sempre que for postar código, utilize marcações para facilitar a leitura. Coloque entre crases o pedaço de código no meio do texto.

Comment: A tela fica branca, e tirando o if volta a funcionar

Comment: Editei a resposta com um código de verificação já pronto, mas caso prefira mudar pra `$_GET`, não esqueça de mudar tanto na condição como no bloco.

Comment: Valeu brother, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que cURL possa ajudar.

```
$foto = $_GET['imagem_url'];

$ch = curl_init($foto);
curl_exec($ch);
$HTTPCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if($HTTPCode == '200'){
    echo '<img src=".'$foto.'">';
}
else 
    echo 'Imagem não encontrada';
```