# Verificar se um link esta ativo ou quebrado

Tags: php, link

Gostaria de saber como posso usar o PHP para verificar se o *link* de *download* de servidores como Mega, Google, Filehero entre outros estão ativos caso não estejam apresente o resultado de *link offline*.

No caso esta [*URL*](http://mega.co.nz/#!0Q9zGIwb!v_CAoVPESQ9TExR7H66kA_ZPjjaZCZtBUHZE5_OmcIc)  esta *offline*, como posso saber se um determinado *link* está *off*? de modo programático.

Achei vários códigos para validar existência de paginas na internet, com tudo não valida *links* de servidores.

Achei esse código na internet, porem não funciona devidamente pois mesmo se o link estiver online o código coloca o resultado como link quebrado como posso concertar isso nesse código ? Ou alguem poderia me passar um que funcione para qualquer link de download do mega, 4shared, minhateca etc...

```
<?php 

$url = 'http://mega.co.nz/#!0Q9zGIwb!v_CAoVPESQ9TExR7H66kA_ZPjjaZCZtBUHZE5_OmcIc'; 
$result = @file_get_contents($url); 

// verifica se a url existe 
if ($result !== false): 
// procura pelo id do formulário catcha id='captchaform' 
$pos = stripos($result, 'captchaform'); 

// se encontrar o id='captchaform' então é a página dos downloads 
if ($pos !== false): 
echo 'Url On'; 
endif; 

else: 
echo 'Url off!'; 
endif; 

?>
```

Comment: Já leu sobre a API do *Mega*?

Comment: http://julien-marchand.fr/blog/using-the-mega-api-with-php-examples/

Comment: mais ai só verifica no caso o do mega preciso que verifique qualquer link.

Comment: Então essa pergunta pode resolver seu problema, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1819/como-verificar-se-uma-imagem-existe-num-url-remoto

Comment: mande-me uma url valida

Comment: como no momento estou meio corrido, vou passar por aqui, tenta dar uma olhada aqui https://github.com/codeguy/modern-php/tree/master/04-components/url-scanner-component que deve te ajudar, depois mais tarde, se der, eu tento dar uma resposta melhor com isso! Resumindo, é um exemplo do livro, que verifica se a url esta valida ou não!

Comment: Dei uma atualização na pergunta.

Comment: @Rodrigo Aquele código que postei somente verifica se o código da resposta indica se a requisição foi sucedida, testei aqui somente com o Mega, e pareceu funcionar. Porém, se você pretende verificar *links* de uma gama maior de *servers*, use o http://urlchecker.org/ há inclusive uma API.

Comment: Ok obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isto é realizar uma solicitação e verificar se o código de resposta é *200*, que indica que a solicitação foi bem-sucedida.

Veja um exemplo utilizando a [biblioteca `cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.curl.php):

```
/*
  Argumentos:
    $url:    A URL a ser verificada
    $limite: Define o tempo limite. É opcional, o padrão é 25s
  Retorno:
    true:  Se a URL estiver disponível
    false: Se a URL estiver quebrada
*/
function verificarLink($url, $limite = 25){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);        // Inicia uma nova sessão do cURL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $limite); // Define um tempo limite da requisição
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);     // Define que iremos realizar uma requisição "HEAD"
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); // Não exibir a saída no navegador
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Não verificar o certificado do site

    curl_exec($curl);  // Executa a sessão do cURL
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200; // Se a resposta for OK, a URL está ativa
    curl_close($curl); // Fecha a sessão do cURL

    return $status;
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
$link = "http://mega.co.nz/#!0Q9zGIwb!v_CAoVPESQ9TExR7H66kA_ZPjjaZCZtBUHZE5_OmcIc";
$status = verificarLink($link);
if ($status) {
    echo "O link fornecido está disponível!";
} else {
    echo "O link fornecido está quebrado.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você olhar pro URL, ele termina com `#!` e um monte de caracteres estranhos: o `#!` indica que, na realidade, quem redireciona o usuário pro lugar certo é um pedacinho de JavaScript que roda no browser do usuário. Você poderia rodar o JavaScript da página usando algo tipo o [phpjs](http://include-once.org/p/phpjs/), mas a solução mais sensata é tentar converter esses URLs usando [o `_escaped_fragment_` do Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) (no caso, você tentaria acessar `http://mega.co.nz/?_escaped_fragment_=0Q9zGIwb!v_CAoVPESQ9TExR7H66kA_ZPjjaZCZtBUHZE5_OmcIc`, mas não está claro pra mim se o `mega.co.nz` segue a especificação do Google).