# Como verificar se uma imagem (arquivo físico) existe ou não em um servidor web externo através de uma URL absoluta

Tags: php

Normalmente utilizo a função ***file_exists*** do ***PHP*** para fazer isso quando estou desenvolvendo remotamente, porém agora preciso saber quando a imagem existe ou não em uma ***URL*** absoluta de um servidor web externo.

*Editando a pergunta para incluir mais informações:*

Testei todos esses métodos tanto no servidor local quanto em um servidor web **diferente de www.issam.com.br** e nenhum retorna o valor correto, alguém sabe dizer se é possível isso?

```
Imagem que existe = http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356031.jpg
Imagem que não existe = http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356030.jpg

if(file_exists('http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356030.jpg')){
   echo"sim";
}else{
  echo"nao";
}


if(file_get_contents('http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356030.jpg')) {
   echo "Existe";
}else{
   echo"nao";
}

$arquivo = 'http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356030.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($arquivo);
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   echo 'Arquivo não existe.';
}else {
echo 'Arquivo existe.';
}

$arquivo = 'http://www.issam.com.br/ximages/produtos/356030.jpg';
if (!$fp = curl_init($arquivo)){
   echo 'Arquivo não existe.';
}else{
    echo 'Arquivo existe.';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer de várias formas.

Além da opção citada pelo @Lucas Caires, poderia ser...

Usando `get_headers`:

```
$arquivo = 'http://www.seu_dominio.com.br/seu_caminho/absoluto/arquivo.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($arquivo);
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    echo 'Arquivo não existe.';
}else {
     echo 'Arquivo existe.';
}
```

Usando CURL:

```
$arquivo = 'http://www.seu_dominio.com.br/seu_caminho/absoluto/arquivo.jpg';
if (!$fp = curl_init($arquivo)){
   echo 'Arquivo não existe.';
}else{
   echo 'Arquivo existe.';
}
```

**NOTA:** Estas duas opções são interessantes pois não fazem o download do arquivo completo. Ficando muito mais rápido.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: POR FAVOR, pesquise se já não existem respostas no site que respondam a duvida, fico muito grato se favorecer as respostas existentes http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1819/3635

Comment: Obs: **não fui** eu quem negativou a sua resposta, mas eu já lhe orientei mais de uma vez sobre como marcar a pergunta como duplicata

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento... agradeço mais uma vez a atenção. Irei me esforçar para não responder antes de checar.

Comment: Não é duplicata pois a pergunta é para servidores externos e não servidor próprio ou remoto como diz a resposta do Kenny Rafael. Já havia tentando essa resposta porém não funciona. Vou tentar essas dos amigos Lucas Caires e Allan Andrade.

Comment: Denis, me avisa se deu certo.

Comment: @denis servidor remoto e servidor externo é praticamente a mesma coisa, o que você quer dizer com URL absoluta? Seria isso `/home/user/teste/image.jpg` ou seria isso `http://siteexterno.com/image;jpg` ou seria isso `smb://shared/image.jpg`. Por favor de mais detalhes.

Comment: Em breve testo Allan. Guilherme seria http://siteexterno.com/image.jpg Testei com file_exists e não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) para isso.

```
<?php
if(file_get_contents('http://www.exemplo.com.br/imagem.jpg')) {
 echo "Existe";
}
?>
```

Lembrando para essa função funcionar, você precisará ativar o **allow_url_fopen** no seu php.ini. Caso você não consiga ativar isso, há a alternativa de usar a biblioteca cURL. [Aqui tem um exemplo de uso](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#82255).