# Como verificar se a página existe?

Tags: php

URL quando a pessoa esta na pagina para escolher o episodio pode ser `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie/the-walking-dead` ou `http://www.localhost/seriados/anime/the-walking-dead`

URL quando a pessoa está na página para assistir pode ser
  `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie/the-walking-dead/episodio-02-the-walking-dead/dublado` ou `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie/the-walking-dead/episodio-02-the-walking-dead/legendado`

```
//url padrao
$urlBase="http://www.localhost/seriados";

//pega o valor url do .htaccess
$url = $_GET['url'];

//cria um array depois da barra
$urlE = explode('/',$url);
if(isset($urlE['0'])){

   //valor serie ou anime
   $arquivo = $urlE['0'];

}

if(isset($urlE['1'])){

   //valor do slug "the-walking-dead"
   $post = $urlE['1'];
}

if(isset($urlE['2'])){

   //valor do slug_episodio "episodio-02-the-walking-dead"
   $ep = $urlE['2'];
}

if(isset($urlE['3'])){

   //valor do audio_episodio "dublado" ou "legendado"
   $audio = $urlE['3'];
}

//paginas do meu diretorio
$paginas = array('contato');

if(isset($arquivo) && in_array($arquivo,$paginas)){
   //se existir a pagina contato
   include_once("includes/$arquivo.php");
}

//se existir o valor $ep ($urlE['2']) na URL 
elseif(isset($ep) && !empty($ep)){
   include_once("includes/episodio.php");
}

//veririca se existe o valor "serie" ou "anime" ($urlE['0'])
elseif(isset($arquivo) && isset($post)){

    //se nao existir $urlE['1'] quer dizer ele esta na home
    if(empty($post)){
       header("Location: ".$urlBase."");
    }else{
       //pagina onde a pessoa escolhe a o episodio desejado
       include_once("includes/serie.php");
    }

}else{
    //se nao existir existir nenhuma acima, manda pra home
    include_once("includes/home.php");
}
```

Até aqui tudo certo, agora vamos para a pagina `serie.php`, agora como eu podia verificar se a URL existe, fiz desse jeito porém algumas coisas não funcionam

```
//se nao existir nada na URL ($$urlE['0']) manda pra home 
if(empty($arquivo)){
  header("Location: ".$urlBase."");
}

//faz uma contagem na coluna slug_serie
$contaSeriado=$conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(slug_serie) AS contaSlug FROM `seriados` WHERE `slug_serie` = '$post'");

if(isset($slug_serie)){
    $contaSeriado->bindValue(":slug_serie",$slug_serie,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$conta=$contaSeriado->rowCount();
$contaSeriado->execute();
$cs=$contaSeriado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($cs as $l){

   //se o slug_serie da URL for diferente do slug_serie banco manda pra home
   if($l->contaSlug<=0){
      header("Location: ".$urlBase."");
   }else{
     //exibo os detalhes da serie
   }

}
```

Nessa página o formato da URL dela e assim `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie/the-walking-dead` se o cara deixar ela assim `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie` ou escrever qualquer nome sem a barra ela não redireciona para home

Tenho outra pagina também, que e responsável em exibir o episodio escolhido, nessa eu não tenho ideia de como verificar as URL, o formato da URL dessa página e assim `http://www.localhost/seriados/serie/the-walking-dead/episodio-02-the-walking-dead/dublado` alguém saberia me dizer como arruma isso, ou dar alguma ideia ?

Comment: Quando você digita uma URL inexistente, como http://www.localhost/seriados/serie o que ocorre? Erro 404?

Comment: @RenatoNascimento eu nao tenho essa pagina de erro, meu objetivo e mandar direto pra home, ai oque acontece, a pagina fica toda branca

Comment: dê uma lida aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1819/como-verificar-se-uma-imagem-existe-num-url-remoto